# Odd poop, clear jelly like, with fresh blood and eating grass

Tags: dogs, health, eating, defecation, digestion

My dog went out and ate a bunch of grass then immediately came in the house and pooped the undirected grass. It was encased in a clear jelly like substance with fresh blood mixed in. Earlier in the day her poop was normal. Should I be worried?

Comment: the poop the dog did wouldn't have contained the grass she just ate, it would've been grass eaten from an earlier time. Yes fresh blood in the poo is not good and impossible to diagnose safely over the internet. Please take your dog to a vet and let us know how she is.

Answer (score 1):

Mucous and blood in the stool can happen for a number of reasons, if it's routine for her to eat an assortment of things from outside then it's possible she got into something that irritated her bowels.

Bland diet (hamburger + rice) for the next 24 hours, if no improvement it warrants a vet visit to rule out some causes (parasites, bacterial overgrowth, Inflammatory bowel disease etc.) and to be placed on the correct medications.